# WebM video doesn't play on Safari browser IOS iPhone

Tags: iphone, video, next.js, safari, html5-video

```
<video autoPlay={true} loop={true} controls={false} muted playsinline id="video">
              <source src={`${...}`} type="video/webm"></source>
            </video>
```

I tried usng `playsinline` but didn't work.

Comment: It's not fully supported - https://caniuse.com/webm

Answer (score 0):

For iOS devices, browser doesn't support webm format.